# MVC 5: Obtaining the Refering URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

The controller class in MVC 5 apparently does not implement the `Request.UrlReferrer` as this property is always null and the VS says

> When overridden in a derived class, get's information about the referrer URL ...

I check the `ServerVariable` and the `Headers` properties by serializing them as XML files to explore their contents and I did not found any key that returns the referring URL.

I already know how to manually handle this for example by `TempData`, `Keeping the URL in session`, `ActionFilterAttribute for that`. I'm not after any of these.

I simply wanna know if such behavior is implemented in MVC 5 by default and if so where I can find it.

> **The answers in other StackOverFlow posts are outdated**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Request.UrlReferrer` will give you a `Uri` object when you are visiting the current page from a link in another web page. If you are directly accessing the url ( *as you do when you hit F5 button in Visual studio*), you will get a null value as the return value of `Request.UrlReferrer` call as there we are directly going to this page.

To verify this you can do this.

Have 2 action method

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   var r = Request.UrlReferrer;
   return View();
}
public ActionResult About()
{ 
   return View();
}
```

Now in the about view(`~/Views/Home/About.cshtml`), add this makrup to generate a link to your index action.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Index","Index","Home")
```

Put a breakpoint in the Index action so you can inspect the `r` varibale value.
Run your app. Go to About page, Click on your Index link and see what value you get in the `r` variable when the breakpoint hits the Index action.

Comment: Well it's always null, and I did check it like that already. The actual case is an exception handler in an action so when the exception is caught, the custom error tries to get the referrer but that is always null.

Comment: Logically speaking the `Request.UrlReferrer` should show the address of the action where the error is coming from but it's always null.

Comment: @Arrrr Not if it's the first request to the action, then it will be null. Are you sure that you are calling the action from another page, and not directly as the first request?

Comment: You have a custom action filter for exception handling ? You need to provide proper information about your use case so people can help you